# How do I go about factoring $x^n-4n-4$?

Tags: factoring

How do I factor $$x^n-4n-4$$ (please provide steps)

I have a test in a few hours and would just like to understand this asap.

Thank you.

Comment: $x^n-4n-4{}{}{}$?

Comment: Yes, I know the solution, but do not understand how to arrive at it

Comment: You have a test in $2$ hours and you still have hope? I have a test in two days and I already gave up :(

Comment: Teacher will hopefully curve the overall average of the course. so I do have hope

Comment: ASAP: I don't have the faintest idea how you still hope to master this stuff in the few hours left for your exam...

Comment: OP, are you working in a certain (prime) field or something?

Comment: What have you written so far? This is not a home-work-completion site. Show us what you've tried so far, where you are facing problems. Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Well, if they're going to factor out the grade, then you better do **not** answer questions like this one so that the curve will be "more benefitial" for you....:)

Comment: If you know the answer, tell us it, because I can't tell what you mean by the question.

Comment: Ok, the recurrence relation I am working on has the characteristic equation: r^2 - 4r - 4. The next step of finding the solutions to the recurrence relation is to factor. The answer to this is r=2(1+-Sqrt2)

Comment: What does $r^2-4r-4$ have anything to do with $x^n-4n-4$?  If you are asking how to factor a quadratic, that can be simply done using the quadratic formula, the factors of the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ are $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, but that again has nothing to do with the question in the body of your post

Comment: As for factoring $x^n-4n-4$, you have $-4n-4$ is just a constant with respect to $x$, so lets just call that $a$ instead... factoring $x^n-a$ can be done in a number of ways, but how far you want to factor is personal choice but I doubt you can get to linear only... for example you could begin with $x^n-a = (x-\sqrt[n]{a})(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a^{1/n} + x^{n-3}a^{2/n}+\dots+a^{(n-1)/n})$, or if $n$ were even you could go as $x^n-a = (x^{n/2}-\sqrt{a})(x^{n/2}+\sqrt{a})$.  All said and done however, I expect that you just have made a serious typo and don't really know what it is you are trying to ask

Comment: r^2-4r-4 is the character equation of x^n-4n-4. Thank you very much for the quadratic formula

Comment: I have *never* heard of a characteristic equation of a polynomial.  I know of characteristic equations to recurrence relations, but $x^n-4n-4$ is not a recurrence relation.  An example of a recurrence relation with $r^2-4r-4$ as its characteristic equation would be $x_n=4x_{n-1}+4x_{n-2}$

Comment: Sorry my brain is fried from studying so much, that is the actual recurrence relation which turned into r2−4r−4.

Comment: To clarify, I am able to use the Quadratic formula to establish the roots of a recurrence relation?

Comment: The quadratic formula I gave earlier will tell you the roots to a quadratic polynomial, which can be useful for finding closed forms for some *second order* linear recurrence relations, but not every recurrence relation will be linear and not every linear recurrence relation will be second order.  It will be of absolutely no (*direct*) help for finding roots to the characteristic equation of third order recurrence relations for example.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your assistance

Comment: Murdered that final :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To factor

$$x^n-4(n+1)$$

find the $n$ $n$-th roots of $4(n+1)$, call them $w_0,w_1,\cdots,w_{n-1}$, then

$$x^n-4(n+1)=(x-w_0)(x-w_1)\cdots(x-w_{n-1})$$

You know that

$$ w_0=\sqrt[n]{4(n+1)}e^{2\pi i/n} $$

etc.